# Are Asian Pears Bitter? Mine Was

Tags: fruit

I bought an Asian pear the other day and let it ripen for about a week since it was still very firm when I bought it.  When I ate it, I found it to be very bitter and almost inedible because of its rotten taste.  However, it looked fine, came from a good grocery store and was stored properly.  I've never had one before, so I don't know if they are usually so bitter.  Did I have a rare experience or are they usually so bitter?

I was so surprised because the sign at the store for the Asian pears said they were sweat, juicy and the most flavorful of pear varieties.

I looked online and found no mention of Asian pears being bitter, so I suspect it was just this one pear, but maybe I just didn't do enough research.

[image: Asian pear]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you got a bunk pear.

I've never had a bitter asian pear. The grocery store sign is correct; they are sweeter and juicier than other pears.

Unlike other pears, asian pears are typically picked when ripe. They also are supposed to be quite firm and crisp when ripe. You should be able to smell the sweetness of a ripe asian pear. Maybe your week "ripening" it spoiled it? Not sure what the conditions were, but it is strange because they have an excellent shelf life.

Comment: I think I'll buy another one or two and try again.  The pear looked fine and when I cut it, all the flesh looked fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

Was it possibly more astringent than bitter? I find that the skin can be a bit astringent. But the flesh should be crispy, juicy and sweet with no more bitterness than, say, an apple.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, most farmers sell them at their peak of ripeness. It's best to eat them within a day.  The sweetness is on the mild level, like water crest fruits such as watermelon. Chilled taste better.